# Is it plugin options or plugin’s options?

Tags: grammar, possessives, apostrophe

> You can pass the plugin’s options in here.
>
> The plugin’s options have been saved.

or

> You can pass the plugin options in here.
>
> The plugin options have been saved.

I never know which option to choose.

Can someone enlighten me?

NOTE: I know that *’s* means possession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different possibilities:

1. "Plugin" is treated as an adjective on the noun "options"
2. The noun "options" is regarded as being owned by a noun "plugin"

In the first case you would say, eg, "The plugin options have been saved" or just "Plugin options have been saved".  Note that it's equally valid (though less specific) to say just "Options have been saved".

What you're saying here is not that the options of a specific plugin have been saved but rather that some number of options in the category of "plugin options" have been saved, without specifying which specific plugin these options might belong to.

In the second case you would say "The plugin's options have been saved."  The word "The" is not optional in this case, since you're referring to a specific plugin and it's specific options.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the simpler "plugin options".  Computer jargon very rarely uses possessives; it prefers to stack noun after noun, using almost any noun as an adjective.

Comment: Not sure this has anything to do with possessive being "less common in computer jargon". When I think of "<noun phrase> options" I am straining to think of *any* common example that includes a possessive noun phrase. For example: *delivery options*, *travel options*, *shopping options* are all formed identically to "plugin options", and they have nothing to do with computers.